# how to check if two datetime between current times

Tags: php

i wanna check if current time is between current day 8AM and next day 2AM

i did try

```
$currentTime = date('h:i A', time());
$startTime = "8:00 AM";
$endTime = "2:49 AM";
if ((strtotime($currentTime) >= strtotime($startTime)) && (strtotime($currentTime) <= strtotime($endTime))) {
  // do something
}
```

what should result

`true`

but its return

`false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dates are part of your logic, then use them. You can utilize `DateTime`'s relative formats:

```php
$start = new DateTime('today 08:00 AM');
$end = new DateTime('tomorrow 02:00 AM');
$current = new DateTime();
if ($start <= $current && $current <= $end) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: i am thinking if current time 1 am then??

Comment: 1 AM of which *day*?

Comment: next day 1 AM before 2AM

Comment: Change this: `$current = new DateTime('tomorrow 01:00 AM')` and test. It will be true.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your code a bit and it working

```
$currentTime = date('h:i A');  //UTC time
$startTime = "8:00 AM";
$endTime = "11:50 PM";

if ((strtotime($currentTime) >= strtotime($startTime)) && (strtotime($currentTime) <= strtotime($endTime))) {
    print 'test';
}
```

Comment: i want between current day mrng 8:00 AM and next day 2:49 am